# Stepping Through with NUnit in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, nunit, testdriven.net

I installed TestDriven.Net after installing NUnit.  When in VS, I run all tests, they run but I want to be able to step into my method somehow to see where the test went wrong in the target method.  Meaning I want to step into the target method and see the point of failure before it comes back to NUnit to give me the test result.

I'm not sure how to get this to work...so far no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a breakpoint on the method (either production or test) and use "Test With > Debugger" as described in the [TestDriven.Net QuickStart guide](http://www.testdriven.net/quickstart.aspx#Debug).

Comment: yea that's exactly what I did.  I just did something stupid...it works.  Duh.

Comment: Hey john, unrelated question.  Do you use private fields at the top of your test classes that you're using throughout your test class?  For example I created a wrapper that wraps an API.  I don't want to create a bunch of new instances of the wrapper meaning creating an instance in every test method.  Just use a private _wrapper field defined in my class right?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: In most test frameworks I use, each test method is called with a fresh instance of the test case anyway - which is what I'd want. I wouldn't want any changes made by previous tests to affect later ones. Is your wrapper really that expensive to create?

Comment: Thanks!  well it's not that expensive now but I don't like the "well it's not that big of an app or it's not that bit of an x" kind of attitude.  So to keep it extensible you think that even the instance of the wrapper proxy client should be re-created per test method?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: Well I've no idea what your wrapping, what it's a proxy for etc - it's not a matter of making it *extensible*, it's a matter of making it *repeatable* and *independent*. One test shouldn't depend on another, and creating new instances - at least of any *mutable* objects - helps ensure that.